# I have a object in my Parent component and I have to pass that object in my child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular10

So I have Patient-prescription.components.ts this parent component and I have to pass object from here to this child component Patient-prescription-expand-view.component.ts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An `@Input` and attribute binding. Strongly suggest you either follow the Angular tutorial or do a beginner course in Angular, as this is very very basic.